# Issue with INSERT INTO

Tags: vba, ms-access

i wrote that code  which should do compare the values of two table and only insert the records that is  newly added in the first table and it gives me an error of not finding the Frs

```
Private Sub MainButt_Click()
Dim mydb As Database
Dim Frs As DAO.Recordset
Dim Srs As DAO.Recordset
Dim testdate As String
Dim strsql As String
Dim secstrsql As String
Dim sqlinsert As String

strsql = "SELECT * FROM Firstable "
secstrsql = "SELECT * FROM secondtable"
Set Frs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strsql)
Set Srs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(secstrsql) 
 sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO Srs ( StransfereDate, transfereName, transfereId, transferAddress ) SELECT Frs.FtransfereDate, Frs.Tname, Frs.TId, Frs.TAddress FROM Frs  WHERE NOT EXISTS  (SELECT *  FROM Srs   WHERE (  Frs.FtransfereDate=Srs.StransfereDate AND Srs.transfereName=Frs.Tname AND Srs.transfereId =Frs.TId AND Srs.transferAddress=Frs.TAddress  )    )"
            DoCmd.SetWarnings False
CurrentDb.Execute sqlinsert
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use VBA recordsets in SQL statements. SQL must refer to tables (or saved queries).

You need something like this:

```
INSERT INTO secondtable ( ... ) 
SELECT ... FROM Firstable 
WHERE ...
```

Comment: i tried this before and i got another error message that says too few arguments with the docmd.runsql command

Comment: @AhmedGammal Just replace `... FROM Frs...` with `... FROM Firstable as Frs...` and `... FROM Srs...` with `... FROM secondtable as Srs...` in your `sqlinsert`. Also `Debug.Print sqlinsert` and use code in a query for more help.

Comment: ^This. See [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271) @AhmedGammal